# How can I pass on called function value in Python?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a code like this:

```
def read_from_file(filename):
    list = []
    for i in filename:
        value = i[0]
        list.append(value)
    return list

def other_function(other_filename):
    """
       That's where my question comes in. How can I get the list
       from the other function if I do not know the value "filename" will get?
       I would like to use the "list" in this function
    """
read_from_file("apples.txt")
other_function("pears.txt")
```

I'm aware that this code might not work or might not be perfect. But the only thing I need is the answer to my question in the code.

Comment: 1. Return the list from the first function. 2. Pass it to the second function. What's the problem? At the moment, you're just ignoring it!

Comment: The thing is that i must not change the name of the function so i cant make it into two variable function.
It must remain as other_function("pears.txt")

Comment: Then you will have to use global state, which is very poor practice - you should complain to whoever set you this homework.

Comment: And globals are not allowed either

Comment: In that case I don't know how you're expected to get access to the list content inside the second function.

Answer (score 1):

You have two general options.  You can make your list a global variable that all functions can access (usually this is not the right way), or you can pass it to `other_function` (the right way).  So

```
def other_function(other_filename, anylist):
    pass # your code here

somelist = read_from_file("apples.txt")
other_function("pears.txt.", somelist)
```

Comment: The thing is that i must not change the name of the function so i cant make it into two variable function.
It must remain as other_function("pears.txt")

Comment: And I'm not allowed to use globals

Comment: If we're going to be pedantic, I'm going to point out two things: changing the definition of the function does not change its name, and other_function has access to the global namespace without creating a global variable.  Oh, and as long as your instructor is giving troll homework, you should inform them that it's horrendously bad practice to use keywords as variable names (list).

Comment: Like I said.. I just wrote it as an example, the actual code is a bit bigger

Answer (score 0):

You need to "catch" the value return from the first function, and then pass that to the second function.

```
file_name = read_from_file('apples.txt')
other_function(file_name)
```

Comment: The thing is that i must not change the name of the function so i cant make it into two variable function.
It must remain as other_function("pears.txt")

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the returned value in a variable before you can pass it onto another function.

```
a = read_from_file("apples.txt")
```

Comment: That's not actually true, you could do this without ever assigning the list to a name outside the functions.

Comment: Agreed.  It's usually cleaner to do it lanceavil's suggested way, though.

Answer (score -1):

There are at least three reasonable ways to achieve this and two which a beginner will probably never need:

1. Store the returned value of `read_from_file` and give it as a parameter to `other_function` (so adjust the signature to `other_function(other_filename, whatever_list)`)
2. Make `whatever_list` a global variable.
3. Use an object and store `whatever_list` as a property of that object
4. (Use nested functions)
5. (Search for the value via garbage collector [`gc`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html) ;-)
   )

### Nested functions

```
def foo():
    bla = "OK..."

    def bar():
        print(bla)
    bar()

foo()
```

### Global variables

- [What are the rules for local and global variables in Python?](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) (official docs)
- [Global and Local Variables](http://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php)
- [Very short example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/423596/562769)

### Misc

- You should not use [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) as a variable name as you're overriding a built-in function.
- You should use a descriptive name for your variables. What is the content of the list?
- Using global variables can sometimes be avoided in a good way by creating objects. While I'm not always a fan of OOP, it sometimes is just what you need. Just have a look of one of the plenty tutorials (e.g. [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)), get familiar with it, figure out if it fits for your task. (And don't use it all the time just because you can. Python is not Java.)

Comment: Would the person who downvoted this please explain why?